# Obtaining selected cell value from a wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, cell

I am trying to get the cell value from a DataGrid on a WPF form.

The code below loops through the rows just fine.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
    TextBlock cellContent = dataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
    if (cellContent != null)
    {
        object item = dataGrid.Items[i];
        dataGrid.SelectedItem = item;
        dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);
        row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        break;
    }
}
```

However I am stuck a bit. 
I need just the Cell value.
And I only ever get Null in my cellContent value.

All the other examples pass in a column name to select a value....however I don't know what cell they will select. So I need to get the header value along with the cell value when they click...or right click the cell.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but try setting the **SelectionUnit** property on the datagrid to **Cell** (the default is FullRow)